# Hashing an input

Tags: hash

I'm writing a protocol that requires users to not be able to see previous input. Is it possible to hash a users input and send the parameter as the hashed version of the input?

Comment: yep, that is how ENS works, the input is the hash of the domain name, so during the auction nobody knows what the name is, unless of course if they don't run brute force on your hash and succeed in guessing it

Answer (score 0):

Everything in blockchain is public to everyone. You can do it what you saying but people can see the inputs in the transaction's data section. Nevertheless here is your solution:

```
function giveMeTheResult(string memory _input) public pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(bytes(_input));
}
```

And the result is:

[image]